# How can I identify duplicate images using CNN?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am working for a property portal and in our portal customers post several images with watermark and duplicity.

I have created a CNN that can detect good images and watermark, but I am unsure how can I train my model to detect duplicate images?

For example, if a customer posts 2 hall, 2 bedroom, 2 kitchen, how can I make my model to detect duplicate images so that I can take further action upon it like deletion from webpage.

Comment: When you say "duplicate" do you mean that the images are exactly the same (image A has exactly the same bytes as image B)? Or that they contain the same content (e.g. two pictures of the same kitchen, taken from slightly different angles)?

Comment: from different slightly angles

Comment: [tag:triplet-loss] might be helpful. FaceNet uses it to identify faces of the same person taken from different angles/different lighting.

Comment: I will try this definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use an Denoising autoencoder for this? and treat the watermark as gaussian noise that gets filtered in the hidden layer http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html

Comment: I need to study it and will get back to you. Thank you so much for this, such a great help here